# how to edit list directly without display preview

Tags: 2010, list, content-editor-web-part

Newbie SharePoint 2010 question

I opened my View in SharePoint designer 2010

I've got a list and I was able to set linked item property on a column "Contribution"

```
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="Edit"/>
<FieldRef Name="CONTRIBUTION" LinkToItem="TRUE"/>
```

Now the users wants to get into Edit Mode instead of Display. I googled and find similar sites like this :

http://sharepointweblog.blogspot.be/2013/10/sharepoint-open-list-item-directly-to.html

I did split screen Design/Preview in SharePoint designer 2010, do not see any code like. But the issue is I don't see code/word like below "FORM_DISPLAY" or "FORM_EDIT".

Change the HREF property to below property just change the `“$FORM_DISPLAY”` to `“$FORM_EDIT”`

So I how can I make this link click becomes in Edit mode, Why do I not see my

```
{$FORM_EDIT}&ID={$ID}&ContentTypeID={$thisNode/@ContentTypeId}
```

I also tried doing this with jQuery Content editor webpart, but this is not working 
either, the breakpoint hits the "each " but doesn't get into the function detail.
When I click in debugger `"$('.ms-vb2 a[href*="listform.aspx"]')"` it returns an object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
// Change all display form links to edit form links
$('.ms-vb2 a[href*="listform.aspx"]').each(function () {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    link = link.replace("PageType=4", "PageType=6");
    $(this).attr('href', link);
});
});
</script>
```

### The below code is added after discussion as requested:

```
 <a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}', 'img_{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}',event, true);MakeViewLink();return false;">
            <img src="{$imagesrc}" border="0" alt="{$alttext}" id="img_{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}" />
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$fieldname" />
          </a>
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
          <a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}', 'img_{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}',event, false);MakeViewLink();return false;">
            <img src="{$imagesrc}" border="0" alt="{$alttext}" id="img_{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}" />
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$fieldname" />
          </a>
```

============================================================

$(document).ready(function() {
    MakeViewLink();
    alert("in doc ready");
});

function MakeViewLink() {
    alert("makeview");
    $('div[class^="ms-vb2"').find('a').each(function(){
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      if(href != undefined) {
          href = href.replace('PageType=4','PageType=6');
          $(this).attr('href', href);
      }
    });

## }

Comment: Try to make any change (adding a space) and save the page. This will make the XSL visible in the current page.

Comment: I did in code and in design view.. no changes.

Comment: do you have jQuery files installed on your server?

Comment: just checking now... jquery is working, the reason why it was not working was because of grouping. I have 2 groups... Units then Documents. When I use grouping Jquery is not applying, when I removing the groups on the view then it works. But I need to apply groups.

Comment: If you have grouping then it wont work. Also if you have pagination then also the jQuery approach will fail.

Comment: Everywhere I google it propose me to change to FORM_EDIT and Page to 6. In SPD I just see: 
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId..<WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart.. <ParameterBindings>.. <View ..<View ..groupby..<WebPartPages:WikiContentWebpart .. and that's it... no column names or web server controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

**Without Grouping**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div[class^="ms-vb"').find('a').each(function(){
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      if(href != undefined) {
          href = href.replace('PageType=4','PageType=6');
          $(this).attr('href', href);
      }
    });
});
```

**With Grouping**

1. Edit the view aspx page in designer (Edit in Advanced Mode)
2. Look for `javascript:ExpCollGroup(...);return false;"`
3. Change it to `javascript:ExpCollGroup('...');MakeViewLink();return false;"` (Keep the content inside ExpCollGroup
4. Look for `</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>`
5. Paste Below code

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       MakeViewLink();
   }); 

   function MakeViewLink() {
       $('div[class^="ms-vb"').find('a').each(function(){
         var href = $(this).attr('href');
         if(href != undefined) {
             href = href.replace('PageType=4','PageType=6');
             $(this).attr('href', href);
         }
       });
   }
   ```
6. Stop editing and refresh page

Comment: no the query you gave is not working, mines is working, but it doesn't work if I do grouping.

Comment: sorry Corretion... yes, your jquery is working now, but not if I apply grouping on the list. I've 2 group fields, then jquery is not working. I mean it doesn't get in the edit mode.

Comment: sorry but, I don't see anything like "javascript:ExpCol.." in the code. 1) I Open SPD 2) I Open the List 3) Then I rightclick on the View (right part of screen) call CWEdit.aspx 4) I choose Eidt Advanced mode 5) then I goto Code View, but no code is there as you suggest. the below div is empty maybe therefore????? I don't knnow.
<WebPartPages:WikiContentWebpart
 <Content><div>
    &nbsp;</div>
   </Content>
</WebPartPages:WikiContentWebpart>

Comment: In the design mode, click on any of the list field heading and press space bar. Save. And then go to code view and check

Comment: ok we make progress :) now I see the XSL tags, but no javascript:ExpCollGroup even search only for ExpCollGroup but not found.

Comment: are you editing the correct view which has grouping?

Comment: yes. CWEdit.aspx - it's written on my TAB.

Comment: shall I remove the grouping by going to Modify List and remove the column names from grouping and save it and then going back to SPD to check your info?

Comment: @Hashim, finally I saw the Expcol, I had to put a space in the Detail of page next to the + sign then I saw the Expcol, putting other places a space doesn't generate the Expcol code. Now where do I need to put the javascript code after /webpartzone?

Comment: @Hashim it shows like this:    <a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}', 'img_{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}',event, false);return false;">
                <img src="{$imagesrc}" border="0" alt="{$alttext}" id="img_{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}" />
                 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$fieldname" />
              </a>

Comment: Yes so follow my steps, Insert `MakeViewLink();` before `return false;">`

Comment: I have 2 times ExpColl group (I assume because I have 2 groups) I tried in both onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}', 'img_{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}',event, true);MakeViewLink();return false;">

onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}', 'img_{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}',event, false);MakeViewLink();return false;">

the difference is one has true and other one has false parameter (before MakeviewLink)

Comment: and in the JS code you wrote I between </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
.......
  </ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>

see at the dots... but it's not working JS MakeViewLink is not called.

Comment: I think we are nearly get working, the only issue is the place of "function MakeViewLink() {..} " is not correct, because that's not called. I've put "alert in expcolgroup that works fine, but putting the code before /WebpartPages:Webpartzone is not right place, because when I debug it says MaekViewLink not found... Please help the last steps!

Comment: Have you wrapped it between <script> tags?

Comment: yes, tried both. <sript> ..</script> it says value of property is null or undefined in IE debugger (MakeViewLink).. so I copied them before </webpartPages:webpartzone> and when I save the file, it moves the code before </ZoneTemplate> automatically.

Comment: even if I put there just this <script type="text/javascript">
alert('hello'); </script> is not called. so the place of javascript is not correct I assume.

Comment: just for your information. If I put the javascript I get a message at the bottom of the list page "Web Part Error: Unknown server tag. "  If  I remove the javascript code then the message is disappeared.

Comment: Ok Got it working with 1 issue: I moved the Script to after</webpartpages:webpartzone> and change the $('.ms-vb....each(function..) TO  $('.ms-vb2 a[href*="listform.aspx"]').each(function () {
but the issue is: I need to click/expand 1 time the list (plus sign) and click on plus sign again/collapse the sub list and then expand then I see the PageType=6. So to get change the to PageType=6 I need to expand/collaps the list .. how to avoid this...?